# C - remove() doesn't delete with char *

Tags: c, delete-file

I'm trying to delete a file with remove() and for some reason it doesn't work when I give it the path in a char*.
Here's what I have:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){ 

    const char * toDie = "/home/User/Desktop/todie.txt";

    int status = remove(toDie);

    if( status != 0 ){
        printf("Unable to delete the file\n");
    }
}
```

It works fine when I run with

```
 int status = remove("/home/User/Desktop/todie.txt");
```

Can someone shed some light on this?

Comment: you should check `"/home/User/Desktop/todie.txt"` because the program looks fine.

Comment: When the function fails, check the value of [`errno`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/error/errno), using either [`perror`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/perror) or [`strerror`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strerror).

Comment: @Michi the file name is toDie, not todie! grrr.... Should I delete the question?

Comment: @user5646514 You should pay more attention on case sensitive :D

Comment: @user5646514 Please see my Answer.

Comment: There is a closing reason: "This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers [...]"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check if that file exist first, or if you supply the right path, or the right name for that File.

Try this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(void){

    const char * toDie = "/home/User/Desktop/todie.txt";

    FILE *check = fopen(toDie, "r");

    if(!check){
        printf("There is no file with that name\n");

    }

    int status = remove(toDie);

    if( status != 0 ){
        printf("Unable to delete the file\n");
        exit(1);
    }else{
        printf("File removed successfully");
    }
}
```

Probably you noticed that i changed:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){}
```

with:

```
int main(void){}
```

Because, if you run this program with no arguments, than there is no need of:

```
(int argc, char *argv[])
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll definitely start doing this :)

Comment: If you feel that this Answer was ok please Accept it.

Comment: I had to wait 3 minutes for some reason

Comment: @user5646514 Because `remove` return is `0` on success and `-1` when an error is present you don't need `if( status != 0 )` just use `if(status)` .